# How can I make a code section in the Azure DevOps comment collapsable?

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, comments, code-snippets, collapsable

How can I make a code section in the Azure DevOps comment collapsable?

I need this for the cases when I paste a lot of code or JSON. I tried two things.

First, I tried just clicking the `Code` button in the editor. It just adds the gray background, but does not make the section collapsable.
[image]

Second thing I tried is to use the markdown. I put the following text:

```
<details open>
  <summary>Click to collapse</summary>

  var a = 2;
</details>
```

But saving the changes did not render any collapse controls. It just literally displayed the text I put.
[image]

So, is there a way to add the collapsable code sections to the Azure DevOps ticket comments?

Comment: The old comments on Azure DevOps does not support Markdown, so that's why we cannot use Markdown systax there. But according to this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/markdown-editor-for-comments-preview/), Markdown editor for comments is in preview. Maybe you can try to opt-in to this private preview. Until then, to answer you, as far as I know, there is no way to make collapsable sections in the comments.